# Create a Taskbar Icon in Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: taskbar, windows-mobile-6.5

Hi All,

I have a requirement to build an app for windows mobile 6.5, which will display an icon in the taskbar (at the top to the left of the volume,clock and wireless icons) and respond to an onclick event. I have found references describing how to display icons in the system tray, but that does meet the requirement. Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Damien.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the notification API. The taskbar is able to hold user notifications.

Here is a compact framework article about that: http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/104

I also used user notification in my PingAlert code: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2011/03/01/mobile-development-pingalert-watch-your-servers-2/ (look at showNotification function at bottom).