# How to add image icon to title bar and hide bottom bar in Compact Framework.?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows

1) I want to add an logo(Image) in the Form Header. How do I do that ?
2) In the windows phone a bottom bar appears with the sign of a keyboard. How do I remove this bar as I am using my custom keyboard. ?

Title Bar

[image: Bottom Bar]

Answer (score 0):

The bottom bar can be 'removed' by removing (set to null) the mainmenu of the form.

The caption bar (top bar) can not be latered easily, it is shared between all windows on the Windows Mobile device. The screen shot shows a windows mobile screen of windows mobile 6.x before 6.5. Is this your target device using. I ask as the start menu icon will move to the bottom of the screen into the menu bar for windows mobile 6.5.
The top bar is called the taskbar and holds notification icons. You need to use the notification API to add a notification icon to the taskbar: [Create a Taskbar Icon in Windows Mobile 6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907228/create-a-taskbar-icon-in-windows-mobile-6-5)