# Disable default keyboard in compact framework

Tags: windows, compact-framework

I have my own custom keyboard. So I don't want this bottom bar to be present on my screen. PFA. How to disable the default keyboard..[image: default keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same question using the same screen shot last week.

You need to set the form's main menu to null then there will be no menu bar with a SIP symbol inside.

DUPLICATE with [How to add image icon to title bar and hide bottom bar in Compact Framework.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258210/how-to-add-image-icon-to-title-bar-and-hide-bottom-bar-in-compact-framework)